# How to get strings before and after specified text, then print to txt in C#?

Tags: c#, string, text, split

I have a really big `txt` file, (call it `input.txt`). Most of the information is unnecessary for me, but there are a lot of iD-s, which are between the `id=` and `amp`strings.
I want to write every id to a new `txt` file, (`output.txt`) , where every iD is in a new line.

How can I manage this?

https://pastebin.com/5tqAiPUi -- Sample txt

Desired output:

```
1839708603
1845432669
1850285729
100000000530931
100000011404225
```

Comment: By parsing the input file.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: Please, provide an *example* of the file (a relevant excerpt) and the *desired outcome*

Comment: @Brúnó Szubally what I mean is, you should research and spend some effort before asking here. We rather help with problems than do the whole work for you

Comment: From the little details you provide, it sounds like you are dealing with URLs and their query parameters. Treating those as URIs will make it way easier to extract the desired information. If in fact you are parsing logfiles, [LogParser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logparser) is the tool of choice instead of string parsing yourself.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko updated the description.

Comment: E.g.: Iterate over the file till you find `id=`. Then an inner loop till you find the 'amp" string. Write the string in-between to the `output.txt`. Continue looping the outer loop till the next `id=` or end of file.

Comment: @Brúnó Szubally: You, probably, should *depersonalize* the data (get rid of real persons' data)

Answer (score 2):

You can try *regular expressions*:

```
  using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
  using System.Linq;

  ...

  string text = ...;

  string[] ids = Regex
    .Matches(text, "(?:id=)(?<value>[0-9]+)(?:&amp)")
    .OfType<Match>()
    .Select(match => match.Groups["value"].Value)
    .ToArray();
```

If you want to read/write the data from/to the file(s):

```
 File.WriteAllLines(@"c:\Output.txt", Regex
    .Matches(File.ReadAllText(@"c:\Input.txt"), "(?:id=)(?<value>[0-9]+)(?:&amp)")
    .OfType<Match>()
    .Select(match => match.Groups["value"].Value));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this Code helps you to extract:

```
        const string startString = "id=";
        const string endString = "amp";

        string test = "ffvreergverfverid=38338ampvevbevvid=3amp";
        StringBuilder outfile = new StringBuilder();
        do
        {
            int startPos = test.IndexOf(startString);
            int endPos = test.IndexOf(endString);
            outfile.AppendLine(test.Substring(startPos, endPos - startPos));
            test = test.Remove(startPos, (endPos + endString.Length)- startPos);
        }while(test.Contains(startString));
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you are reading URL's

I personally would check out [StreamReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader(v=vs.110).aspx) class, you are going to need to read each character until you find a series of characters, so something like:

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    namespace StrReader
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                bool hit = false;
                string start = "?id=";
                string end = "&amp;";
                string buffer = string.Empty;
                string endBuffer = string.Empty;
                using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"C:\development\zaza.txt"))
                {
                    while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
                    {
                        string value = ((char)sr.Read()).ToString();
                        if(!hit){
                            if (start.IndexOf(value) > -1)
                                buffer = string.Concat(buffer, value);
                            else buffer = string.Empty;
                            hit = string.Equals(buffer, start, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
                            if (buffer.Length >= start.Length && hit)
                                buffer = string.Empty;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (end.IndexOf(value) > -1)
                                endBuffer = String.Concat(endBuffer, value);
                            else
                                endBuffer = string.Empty;
                            buffer = string.Concat(buffer, value);
                            if (endBuffer == end)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(buffer.Substring(0,buffer.Length - endBuffer.Length ));
                                buffer = string.Empty;
                                hit = false;
                            }
                            buffer = string.Concat(buffer, value);
                        }
                    }
                }
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
```

The reason you want to read each character is if you read the entire file into memory you are going to be sad, this will slow your machine down quite badly.

Just some comments on the code above change c:\development\zaza.txt to the big file, also you will need to change the start identifier ?id= to something you need. Finally the end identifier (&) needs to be altered to your requirements.